# Add custom html classes to gutenberg wrapper

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I wanna add custom classes to gutenberg wrapper.

But I wanna be flexible and use the classes from inspectorinput.

How can I do? Block filters don't work a that cause you can just use a special class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Block Filters are used to customize the class that wordpress already adds using following format `wp-block-[plugin_name]-[block-name]`. You can access that using `this.props.className`.
- You can also add the additional classes using Advanced Panel which is present on right sidebar.
- In the end you can use React.js component state to define custom classes (pseudo code is given below).

(Create separate file for this and pass into edit method inside registerBlockType for better structuring else you can write this whole code)

```
class Testing extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      customClasses: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    <InspectorControls>
      <TextControl
        label="Custom CSS Classes"
        value={ this.state.customClasses }
        onChange={ ( content ) => setState( { customClasses: content } ) }
      />
    </InspectorControls>
  }
}
```